# Update table if exits at the time of plugin activation

Tags: wordpress

I have just starting developing a plugin. but dbDelta() doesn't working when i was changed MySQL query and after that i am trying to deactivate and activate plugin further but table doesn't updated using dbDelta() finction.

```
if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'" ) != $table_name ) {

    $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.' (
    id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    product_name text NOT NULL,
    UNIQUE KEY id (id))';

    //reference to upgrade.php file
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
    dbDelta($sql);
}
```

Comment: Show some code please.

Comment: Are you sure the function containing the above code is hooked correctly using register_activation_hook? Maybe show a bit more code?

Comment: yes it working correctly but becuase of this condition it's not update database  if ( $wpdb->get_var( "SHOW TABLES LIKE '$table_name'" ) != $table_name ) {

Answer (score 0):

you'd be better off just checking the table exists by directly calling it...

```
 global $wpdb;
 $table_name= 'name of table without the prefix!'

 if(!isset($wpdb->$table_name)){
     $sql = 'CREATE TABLE '.$table_name.' (
     id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     product_name text NOT NULL,
     UNIQUE KEY id (id))';

     //reference to upgrade.php file
     require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/upgrade.php' );
     $result=dbDelta($sql);
     var_dump($result);
  }
```